# Python: grouping data with saving column value by rule

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to save column value with specific logic after grouping. Here is my dataframe "user_payments":

```
id  createdAt   updatedAt   rentEndAt   rentComplete    status  price   value   debt    attemptsCount   receipt creditCardId    tariffId    rentId
1468    1402    2020-10-02 12:52:03.895405  2020-10-02 19:01:30.917097  2020-10-03 12:52:00 False   succeeded   100.0   100.0   0.0 0   {'id': '27093630-000f-5000-a000-128a5fce2230',...   505 2   637.0
1466    1332    2020-10-01 12:52:04.184750  2020-10-02 12:52:03.915606  2020-10-02 12:52:00 True    succeeded   100.0   100.0   0.0 0   {'id': '2707e4b0-000f-5000-9000-1f9c30bf3898',...   505 2   637.0
1373    1258    2020-09-30 12:52:04.060209  2020-10-01 12:52:04.214163  2020-10-01 12:52:00 True    succeeded   100.0   100.0   0.0 0   {'id': '27069330-000f-5000-a000-1c98d8f9e249',...   505 2   637.0
1318    1212    2020-09-29 12:52:04.018585  2020-09-30 12:52:04.085714  2020-09-30 12:52:00 True    succeeded   100.0   100.0   0.0 0   {'id': '270541b0-000f-5000-8000-1bf091d27028',...   505 2   635.0
1254    1166    2020-09-28 12:52:04.002709  2020-09-29 12:52:04.047428  2020-09-29 12:52:00 True    succeeded   100.0   100.0   0.0 0   {'id': '2703f030-000f-5000-9000-1d3770fbe41a',...   505 2   635.0
```

I am trying to get a table back with renting time interval (that is difference between "createdAt" and "updatedAt" columns) but I need to save a column "status" : ['True','False'] with aggregation rule: if for specific "rentId" there is "False" in column "Status" for any row, there must be "False" value. If there is no "False" - value "True" must be saved.

Here is my grouping formula:

```
time_to_rent = user_payments.groupby(['rentId','creditCardId']).agg({'createdAt': np.min, 'updatedAt': np.max})
time_to_rent['rent_time'] = time_to_rent['updatedAt'] - time_to_rent['createdAt']
```

In result back, it would be ideal to have:

```
        createdAt   updatedAt   rent_time
rentId  creditCardId    status              
637.0   505 2020-09-27 08:44:13.431341  2020-09-27 09:13:45.675674  0 days 00:29:32.244333  False
635.0   505 2020-09-27 09:14:27.188478  2020-09-27 12:51:03.394003  0 days 03:36:36.205525  True
```

can you give me an idea how to add "status" column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It' achievable by using a lambda function:

```
user_payments["status"] = user_payments["rentId"].apply(lambda x: False if False in list(user_payments[user_payments["rentId"] == x]["status"]) else True)
```

This checks if for any of the rows that have the same rentId status is False, it sets it to False otherwise True.

Comment: Thank you for the idea. will try to dig in.
meanwhile: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'toList'

Comment: @OcMaRUS I've edited the code to replace toList() with list()

Comment: Thank you! Yes, it works! One change i made to success: user_payment['rentComplete'] instead of 'status' field.
Much appreciate your help!